# Core Data NSManagedObject error

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode8

I have writing a function in `AppDelegate.m`, which is :

```
-(void)saveContext {

NSError *error = nil;

if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to save changes.");
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
}
```

However, i received an error message :

```
Receiver type 'NSManagedObjectContext' for instance message is a forward declaration
```

My question is : How I could fix it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `managedObjectContext`?

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

Comment: You've @imported CoreData?

Comment: Make sense now and it is working, but can you please explain me why it happens?